# How can I wrap text around a 2 sided object in Photoshop or Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text, distort

I want to wrap a word around a 2 sided shape (as shown in the image below). Envelope distort, wrap text, perspective tool etc. all not the correct solution (or at least, I can't get the result I'm looking for). How can I do this in Photoshop or Illustrator?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple sttrategy.

1. Cut your text into 2 pieces:

   - in illustrator make text, expand, cut via pathfinder or line and divide below.
   - in Photoshop duplicate text and mask the other half.
2. Shear and scale across the cut line.

[image]

**Image 1**: Quick and dirty test, could be done better.

Alternate ideas. This can be done with illustrators extrude tool in illustrator just slice your text and assign it as texture to sides of your extrude.

Also this can be done, quite close, with Envelope distort trick is to rotate the text before envelope. Unfortunately envelope distort will not be sharp at the border, but opens up possibilities for images.

[image]

**Image 2**: Similar more carefully done envelope distort.

Comment: In Photoshop you could draw grids in Vanishing point tool and then in the top left corner choose `Render grids to Photoshop`. It could help with the manual tweaking. I would also recommend making the text a Smart Object beforehand. You can copy&paste pictures to the Vanishing point tool and they will conform to the grid, but you'll be better off doing it a bit more manually, so that you can use Smart objects.

Answer (score 1):

For any shape you can create with Illustrator's limited 3D tools, this is relatively easy. I'll take a cube as an example:

1. Create and lay-out your text;
2. Drag your text object into the `Symbols` palette (<kbd>Window > Symbols</kbd>) to make a new symbol out of it;
3. Draw a square with no stroke;
4. With the square selected, choose <kbd>Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel</kbd>;
5. Switch on 'preview' in the dialogue box and experiment with rotation values and extrusion depth to create the orientation of the cube you need;
6. Click <kbd>Map Art...</kbd>;
7. Choose your new symbol with your text as the symbol to be used and drag it in place on two adjacent faces. You can choose what face your symbol is mapped to with the 'surface' field;
8. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> in both dialogues to commit your effect.

You might want to <kbd>Object > Expand Appearance</kbd> to be able to edit the result and fine-tune placements.